# Как изменить битность версии php на x64?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, миграция

У меня ноутбук с установленной лицензионной **windows 10 x64**. На локальный OpenServer x64 установил чистый сайт на `wordpress`, хочу импортировать на него данные через плагин [All in one wp migration](https://import.wp-migration.com/), которые занимают больше, чем 2гб и получаю вот такую ошибку:

> Unable to import Your PHP is 32-bit. In order to import your file,
>   please change your PHP version to 64-bit and try again.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что можно сделать?

P. s. Пробовал делать все тоже самое через **Bitnami wampstack-7.1.23-1** - все тоже самое

Comment: Поставить 64-битную версию PHP

Comment: laragon - и ставьте, что душе угодно